# Excel 2010 Help Combining Three Different Formulas Into One Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, combine

I am trying to combine three different formulas into one cell, but need help. The cell that is being edited, F3, has several numbers and spaces in the beginning, end, and middle of the number that need to be omitted. The formulas are:

```
=LEFT(F3,LEN(F3)-9
=RIGHT(F3,LEN(F3)-FIND("-",F3))
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(F3,5),(" "),MID(F3,13,50))
```

Comment: Do you want the text results of the formulas to be concatenated into one long string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try concatenating the results with &:

```
=LEFT(F3,LEN(F3)-9)&RIGHT(F3,LEN(F3)-FIND("-",F3))&
CONCATENATE(LEFT(F3,5),(" "),MID(F3,13,50))
```

Comment: or `CONCATENATE(...;...;...)`